# Hibernate cannot find getter

Tags: java, database, hibernate, exception, jboss

I've tried all the answer I've found on stackoverflow and other websites. It's pretty common but looks like each case has its solution. I generated the mapping files using JBoss Hibernate tool on eclipse, so I'm surprised it has mapping error. Hibernate can't find the getter for idparameters (I changed the database column to all lowercase to make sure it's not some case problem, but no avail) Anybody can point out the problem?

Parameter class generated by Hibernate [Parameters.java](http://pastebin.com/AcEGY0mL)

The xml mapping generated by Hibernate [Parameters.hbm.xml](http://pastebin.com/URL63b88)

And [the error itself](http://pastebin.com/MTZRKWdu)

Comment: Did you use the `Parameters` class to generate the hibernate mapping file?

Comment: Sorry I didn't precise, both Parameters.java and Parameters.hbm.xml were generated automatically. On eclipse I just run **run > Hibernate Code generation ..**

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the `Java Bean` naming conventions when using Hibernate. This is what you can do :

1. In the generated `Parameters` class, change `idparameters` to `idParameters`.
2. Change the getter and setter to `getIdParameters` and `setIdParameters(Integer idParameters)`.
3. Regenerate the hibernate mapping file.

Make sure that all your getters and setters follow the `Java Bean` naming conventions. Example : - `getGrayscale`

Comment: I fixed it, regenerated hibernate mapping file, but the problem persists

Comment: @mhfff32 I am sure it's for some other field and not the idParametersField. You need to make sure all your getters and setters follow the Java Bean naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you do a clean java build. You are probably having an old class around that does not have this parameter in it.